# Laravel-How to insert into many to many related tables having already created foreign keys in mysql?

Tags: mysql, controller, insert, foreign-keys, laravel-5.6

When submitting form it throws the error:Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (portal_job.applicant_job, CONSTRAINT applicant_job_applicant_user_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (applicant_user_id) REFERENCES applicants (id) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into applicant_job (applicant_user_id, created_at, job_id, updated_at) values (4, 2018-10-01 23:46:56, 2, 2018-10-01 23:46:56))

How can I do an insert into two related tables? In this case, it would be many to many relationships. I don't know if creating the relationships on mysql beforehand might be causing the problem... if you need more information let me know please. I don't know what else to do because I've already try to do it using attach() and was of no use. Got the same error as well.

This is the code being executed for the task. It first save data into applicants table and then it should do an insert into applicant_job which is the intermediate table but this part is no good.

```
public function store(Request $request, $id) {
    $this->validate($request, [
          'application_letter' => 'required'
      ]);
    $applicant = new Applicant;
    $applicant->application_letter= $request->input('application_letter');
    $applicant->job_id = $request->input('job');
    $applicant->state = 'pending';
    $applicant->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

    $applicant->save();
    $applicant->jobs()->sync([$id],false);

    return redirect("userdashboard");
  }
```

These are the models for the relationships between the tables

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Applicant extends Model
{
     protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

     public $incrementing = false;



      function jobs() {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Job')->withTimeStamps();
      }

      function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','user_id');
     }

     function profile() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Profile', 'profile');
     }
}
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Job extends Model
{


  function category() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\JobCategory');
}
function user() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','user_id');
}

function applicants() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Applicant', 'applicant_job', 'job_id', 'applicant_user_id')->withTimeStamps();
 }
}
```

These are the migrations with their respective foreign keys used for this part of the task.

```
Schema::create('applicants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('application_letter');
            $table->string('state');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('job_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('job_id')->references('id')
            ->on('jobs')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        });
  Schema::create('applicant_job', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('applicant_user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('job_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('applicant_user_id')->references('id')
                ->on('applicants')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('job_id')->references('id')
            ->on('jobs')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->decimal('payment');
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('position_type');
            $table->string('duration_project');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')
                    ->on('job_category')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

This is being done for a small job portal. Any more information you need, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

For Insert/Save you have to use attach();
$parentTable->jobs()->attach($arrayVariable);

For update use : `sync();`
For Delete multiple : `detach();`